# Extending ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity with another object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm currently using Fluent API in which I cannot find many resources regarding extending the Identity model with another object.

Here I have my object called ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }

    public int StaffId { get; set; }
}
```

In which I'd like to map it to my current Staff object:

```
public class Staff
{
    public int StaffId { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public UserTitleEnum Title { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }

    //Add ApplicationUser here?
}
```

I have a few limitations as I'm trying to reuse my models by using a PCL profile 78. Because of this, I cannot include EF libraries and have to use Fluent API.

Is there a simpler way to do this or is this the right approach?  Any information about how to "extend" or "link" the ApplicationUser object further would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your DbContext class override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>().ToTable("Staff");
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(x => x.Staff);
```

i am sorry for my poor english,hope this helpful

Comment: Thanks for this! I actually only needed the bottom portion to make this work.