# asp.net 5 custom IdentityUser properties are null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have this class:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
  public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

When I get user in my controller action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
{
  var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
  if (user != null)
  {
    // **user.Organization is null here**
  }
  return View();
}

...

private async Task<AppUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
{
  return await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(HttpContext.User.GetUserId());
}
```

I can get all user properties, but not the custom one I added. I checked the db and 'Organization' is set for this user in aspnetusers db.

Is there any idea?

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795892/extending-asp-net-mvc-5-identity-with-another-object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like identity framework 3 doesn't support lazy loading. Eager loading doesn't seem to be an option either unless you write your own `FindByIdAsync` method to eager load the dependant tables you want.

it's probably easier to add the OrganizationId as a property

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public  Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

and you will need to create a migration and update your db after the change

which will allow you to reference the organisation id without doing any extra work e.g.

```
var orgId = user.OrganizationId;
```

If you want to get other non primary key properties of the organisation you'll have to create your own Identity Framework 3 `FindByIdAsync` method or alternatively just create a separate db query.